# How to get full URL of image after Amazon S3 upload?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

I need to get full URL of an image which is uploaded to `amazon s3`. I tried following functions. I am using Laravel 5.1.

```
Storage::disk("s3")->url($filename);
Storage::url($filename);
Storage::temporaryUrl('file1.jpg', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
$filesystem->getAdapter()->getClient()->getObjectUrl($bucket, $key);
```

all are showing undefined function `url`(or) `temporaryUrl` (or) `getObjectUrl`.

Comment: Could you paste your definition of the s3 disk from your filesystems.php? It seems it's configured incorrectly and another driver is used, e.g. local, that doesn't provide url methods.

Comment: My s3 configuration in my filesystems.php file is,                               
     's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('S3_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxx'),
            'secret' => env('S3_SECRET', 'yyyyyyyyyyyy'),
            'region' => env('S3_REGION', 'ap-southeast-1'),
            'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET', 'cmol-backup'),
        ],

Comment: My env config file is,                                                                                       S3_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
S3_SECRET=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
S3_REGION=ap-southeast-1
S3_BUCKET=yprivate-testing
S3_URL=https://yprivate-testing.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Could you do dd(get_class(Storage::disk("s3"))); and paste the output?

Answer (score 3):

The `url()` and `temporaryUrl()` methods aren't available in Laravel 5.1 ([FileSystemAdapter - API Reference 5.1](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_temporaryUrl)). They became available as of version 5.4 ([FileSystemAdapter - API Reference 5.4](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_temporaryUrl)).